# How to implement multi-level category recursion function in php?

Tags: php, recursion

I'm doing show tree structure like

```
Level1    level2    level3 ..... level n
   1
   +------1_1
   |         +------1_1_1
   +------1_2
   2
```

**My data** 
***$data =***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [IDCategory] => 1
            [IDCategoryParent] => 4
            [Name] => Thị trường trong nước
            [Slug] => thi-truong-trong-nuoc
            [OrderCategory] => 1
            [Description] => Tin tức Thị trường trong nước
            [Status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [IDCategory] => 3
            [IDCategoryParent] => 3
            [Name] => Thị trường quốc tế
            [Slug] => thi-truong-quoc-te
            [OrderCategory] => 2
            [Description] => Tin tức Thị trường quốc tế
            [Status] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [IDCategory] => 4
            [IDCategoryParent] => 4
            [Name] => Tin tức công ty
            [Slug] => tin-tuc-cong-ty
            [OrderCategory] => 3
            [Description] => Tin tức công ty Tràng An
            [Status] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [IDCategory] => 5
            [IDCategoryParent] => 1
            [Name] => Thực phẩm
            [Slug] => thuc-pham
            [OrderCategory] => 1
            [Description] => Tin tức thực phẩm
            [Status] => 1
        )

)
```

And this was function that i did.

```
 public function recursive($parentid = 1, $data = NULL, $char = '') {
        if (isset($data) && is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
                if ($item['IDCategoryParent'] == $parentid) {
                    $this->recursiveData[$item['IDCategory']] = $item['Name'];
                    $this->recursive($item['IDCategory'], $data, $char);
                    echo $item['IDCategory'];
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->recursiveData;
    }


public function category() {
        $category = new Category();
        $data = $category->selectByStatus(1); // select data from database.

        $recursiveData = $this->recursive(1, $data); // call function 
        return $recursiveData;
    }
```

But the result just only return  1 value is ***"Thực Phẩm"***. I mean my *recursive* function wrong and I don't know why that is incorrect. Please help me.

[UPDATE]: Now i try again with still this code but

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 65488 bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some of your categories have their `IDCategoryParent` set to their own `IDCategory` which will cause issues.

I've changed the ones that reference their own `IDCategory` as `IDCategoryParent` to have value `0`. Which means they are on `level 1`.

Please note that I've just used a simple function in the example code but you can convert it to a class method if you like.

```
$data = [
    [
        'IDCategory' => 1,
        'IDCategoryParent' => 4,
        'Name' => 'Thị trường trong nước',
        'Slug' => 'thi-truong-trong-nuoc',
        'OrderCategory' => 1,
        'Description' => 'Tin tức Thị trường trong nước',
        'Status' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'IDCategory' => 3,
        'IDCategoryParent' => 0,
        'Name' => 'Thị trường quốc tế',
        'Slug' => 'thi-truong-quoc-te',
        'OrderCategory' => 2,
        'Description' => 'Tin tức Thị trường quốc tế',
        'Status' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'IDCategory' => 4,
        'IDCategoryParent' => 0,
        'Name' => 'Tin tức công ty',
        'Slug' => 'tin-tuc-cong-ty',
        'OrderCategory' => 3,
        'Description' => 'Tin tức công ty Tràng An',
        'Status' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'IDCategory' => 5,
        'IDCategoryParent' => 1,
        'Name' => 'Thực phẩm',
        'Slug' => 'thuc-pham',
        'OrderCategory' => 1,
        'Description' => 'Tin tức thực phẩm',
        'Status' => 1,
    ]
];

function createNested($categories, $parentId = 0)
{
    $results = [];
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        if ($parentId == $category['IDCategoryParent']) {
            $nextParentId = $category['IDCategory'];

            $category['children'] = createNested($categories, $nextParentId);

            $results[] = $category;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

$result = createNested($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function multilevel_cat($parent_id){    
    $retVal = array($parent_id);
        
        $sql = "SELECT cat_id,parent_id FROM `cat` WHERE parent_id='".$parent_id."'";
        $res= mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            $retVal = array_merge($retVal,       $this->multilevel_franchise($row['cat_id']));
        }

        return $retVal;
    }
```

this will give all cat id in n lvel

Comment: Please always include a plain English explanation with every answer. Please always demonstrate prepared statements when needing to pass variables into a query.